Prove that the Kronecker product of vectors is a tensor product.
Here I use the definition of tensor product as the following:

A pair $(E\otimes F,\otimes)$, where $E,F,E\otimes F$ are vector spaces and $\otimes: E\times F\to E\otimes F$ is a bilinear mapping, is called a tensor product if and only if the followings are satisfied:

$\text{Im} \otimes$ generates $E\otimes F$.
For any bilinear mapping $\varphi: E\times F\to G$, where $G$ is a vector space, a linear mapping $f:E\otimes F\to G$ such that $\varphi=f\circ \otimes$ can always be found.


I want to show that the mapping $\varphi: \Gamma^n\times \Gamma^m\to M^{n\times m}$, where $\Gamma$ is a field and $M^{n\times m}$ is the set of all $n\times m$ matrices over $\Gamma$, defined by
$$\varphi((a_1,\cdots, a_n),(b_1,\cdots, b_m))=\begin{pmatrix}
a_1b_1 & \cdots & a_1b_m \\
\vdots & & \vdots\\
a_nb_1 & \cdots & a_nb_m
\end{pmatrix},$$
induces a tensor product $(M^{n\times m},\varphi)$.
It is obvious that $\varphi$ is bilinear and the first criterion can be proved easily as the elements in the canonical basis of $M^{n\times m}$ are in $\text{Im}\varphi$, namely the product of two elements in the canonical bases of $\Gamma^n$ and $\Gamma^m$ respectively.
However, I have no clue how can I prove the second criterion. Specifically, I don’t know how can I handle an arbitrary bilinear function and an arbitrary vector space.
Thanks for any answers in advance.

I fixed your definition. The elementary tensors only generate the tensor product.

Hint: when you have done the first part, you know how the linear map must be defined on basis vectors. So...

So let ${\textbf{e}^n_1,\cdots, \textbf{e}^n_n}$ and ${\textbf{e}^m_1,\cdots ,\textbf{e}^m_m}$ be the canonical bases of $\Gamma^n$ and $\Gamma^m$, by some brutal forces we can write $\psi(\textbf{x},\textbf{y})=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^mx_iy_j\psi(\textbf{e}^n_i,\textbf{e}^m_j)$ for the arbitrary bilinear map $\psi$. As $x_iy_j$ is the $ij$ entry of $\mathbf{x}\otimes\mathbf{y}$, we can define a linear map $f$ as the above summation. Yes it works, but it is not as insightful as I have expected...

I suggest to edit your question accordingly. Add your proof and add what you are looking for instead.

Using the method suggested by Matin Brandenburg, let $\{\mathbf{u}_1,\cdots, \mathbf{u}_n\}$ and $\{\mathbf{v}_1,\cdots, \mathbf{v}_m\}$ be the canonical basis of $\Gamma^n$ and $\Gamma^m$ respectively, then for all $\mathbf{x}\in\Gamma^n$ and $\mathbf{y}\in\Gamma^m$, we can write
$$\mathbf{x}=\sum_{i=1}^nx_i\mathbf{u}_i\text{ and }\mathbf{y}=\sum_{j=1}^my_i\mathbf{v}_j,$$
for some $x_i,y_j\in\Gamma$.
For an arbitrary bilinear map $\psi:\Gamma^n\times\Gamma^m\to V$, we have now
$$\psi(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y})=\sum_{i=1}^nx_i\psi(\mathbf{u}_i,\mathbf{y})=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^mx_iy_j\psi(\mathbf{u}_i,\mathbf{v}_j).$$
As $x_iy_j$ are exactly entries of $\varphi(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y})$, we have define a linear map $f:M^{n\times m}\to V$ using the above summation, namely
$$f\left(\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11} & \cdots & a_{1m}\\
\vdots & & \vdots\\
a_{n1} & \cdots & a_{nm}
\end{pmatrix}\right)=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^ma_{ij}\psi(\mathbf{u}_i,\mathbf{v}_j).$$
That $f$ is linear can be easily verified.
